# ArrayList adds both a row and a column with array.add(), how do I only add rows OR columns?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
playerInventory.add(temp);
System.out.println("You've purchased " + temp.getName());
balance -= temp.getPrice();
runningWeight -= temp.getWeight();
System.out.println("Your new balance " + balance + ", and your wagon can carry " + runningWeight + " more pounds of products.\nPress enter to continue shopping.");
Scanner cont = new Scanner(System.in);
String enterToContinue = scan.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < playerInventory.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(playerInventory);
```

The variable `temp` is the return value of a class I made which gets an item from another array which contains `String itemName`, `double price`, and `double weight`. The issue is, when I pass an item into my ArrayList `playerInventory`, it makes a column for the item. Fine. But then when I pass a second item, it makes a second column and puts the item inside there, but then it also creates a new row and copies all items from the first row into the second row. Upon passing a third item, it creates a third column, puts the third item in there, then makes a third row and copies all items down so I have three identical rows.
Like so:

```
[Item1, Item2, Item3]
[Item1, Item2, Item3]
[Item1, Item2, Item3]
```

How do I make it so it just gives me the items in one row?

Comment: Use `System.out.println(playerInventory.get(i));`

Comment: @baraky that's solved it, thanks so much! Quick question, is it normal for the array list to store things this way, or was it just the way I was printing it that makes it look so weird?

Comment: It was just the printing. The array is only 3 elements long [Item1, Item2, Item3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your printing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < playerInventory.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(playerInventory);
```

Will print the same array for `playerInventory.size()` times.

You can either print it only once (remove the `for` loop) or print it as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < playerInventory.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(playerInventory.get(0));
```